# Combining json nodes

Tags: javascript, json

When trying to reiterate over my data I have found it's pushed it into 2 nodes like this:

```
{
  "type": "Element",
  "tagName": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "https://amc-theatres-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/f_auto,fl_lossy,h_300,q_auto,w_200/v1/amc-cdn/production/2/movies/45100/45120/Poster/184127R1.JPG",
    "alt": "Logan",
    "className": [""],
    "dataset": {
      "reactid": 170
    }
  },
  "children": []
},

{
  "type": "Text",
  "content": "Logan2 hr 21 min RGet Tickets"
}
```

Type Element is 0
Type Text is 1

So when I reiterate over it it's returning one fine and the next errors...
How can I combine those into 1 node?

I have been losing my mind for two days trying to figure this out... being new to js and json I just can't seem to get it working...

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide an example of what your desired result is and possibly what you have tried so far?

Comment: I just got back to pull this..  simply because to skip the errors I had to simply do this->   this.activeItem += 2;    It then skips over the nodes that I don't need.... BUT if could offer some insight to possible future issues I would like to combine the "content": into the first node... and get rid of the second node... can concat do that?

Comment: Do you have access to update the source of the JSON? generally it is best to provide data to your app in the format you expect, rather than having to transform it. Could you provide the JS that is making the call? as you could add some transformation code in the success message before saving it to a variable